# Create iCal using Dashcode

Tags: macos, dashcode

I am new to Mac programming. Currently, I need to create a calender like iCal in Mac with monthly, weekly, and daily event creation. Is it possible to create it using Dashcode? Since I am creating a web based application, the calender should be run in Safari and mobile safari. So I have choosen Dashcode. Is my approach is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the application you build will comprise of JavaScript, HTML and CSS2/3. Via Dashcode you will get access to various widgets and as the current trend (or one of them) in web design and development is to use JavaScript, HTML and CSS then i would have thought it was a perfectly good choice.

Whilst it has its quirks and annoyances, Dashcode is a pretty good one stop IDE for this sort of application especially for WebKit based apps to run on Mac and Mac Mobile devices.